# CSS: Text on either side of screen on each line?

Tags: css, alignment

I have some HTML code that goes a little something like this.

```
<p style="text-align:left;">Hello, Sir.</p>
<p style="text-align:right;">How are you today?</p>
```

And I want these lines to be on the same line. Is this possible in CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
<div style="width:content_width">
    <p style="float:left;">Hello, Sir.</p> 
    <p style="float:right;">How are you today?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The only thing is you'd have to remember to clear the floats if there are any elements that come after these two `<p>`s

Comment: You'd only need to float one of those as well.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. Worked well!

Answer (score 1):

look at this this is a better approach http://jsfiddle.net/KWxhg/

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CpMyQ/)

```
p {display:inline;}
p+p{float:right;}
```